# When the shoulders of giants isn't enough?

Tags: society, technological-development

> If I have seen further it is by standing on the shoulders of giants.

This fine quote describes how technological advancement happens as successive generations build upon the accomplishments of the past. But as a society accumulates more and more accomplishments across more and more varied fields, there's more and more to learn before you ever reach the "shoulders" as it were.

What will happen when a society reaches that point where a "lifetime's work" is no longer enough to make discoveries? Will it even happen for humanity? How would it differ for fantasy (or futuristic) worlds with short-lived and long-lived races?

Comment: There's a lot here, and a lot of speculation. I'm not sure this is a very good question for the site. I think it's hard for us to know.

Comment: Perhaps, due to social structures, you might not be born at the feet of giants, but up near their midriff so you have less distance to climb?

Comment: That is why people need to specialize. Unless you a genius Like Da Vinci, it's very difficult to master so many field of study. Everyone learn the bases and then become a specialist in one or two areas. it could also be said that as the knowledge become greater in a particular field, people will choose a specialty inside that field. For example, you have historians that specialize only in the Great War. They know a lot on other eras too but just not as much.

Comment: @vincent - but people already do that. For something like Physics there are ever increasing pre-requisites even for the specialities.

Comment: I'm not convinced this question needs closing (but not completely convinced it doesn't either). Is it worth discussing in chat or in meta since it's gathered a few close votes?

Comment: I want to try and answer this one, but I think the question needs to be modified a little to be a little more focused.

Comment: @TimB - If you think that's helpful. I can see how it's a little broad, but making 3 (or more) separate questions (is this possible? How would humans react N years from now, assuming X, Y, Z? How would a culture with different lifespanned races, assuming A, B, C?) seems worse.

Comment: I would suggest asking the question as to whether humanity would ever reach that point - and then depending on the answers to that you can consider if further follow-on questions are warranted

Comment: It was 1 vote short of closing anyway so I've closed it for now, if you edit the question to focus on just one question then it will go into the re-open queue and we can get some answers (as it's a really interesting question).

Comment: @Timb - understandable. Added a different question the is hopefully suitably restricted and different.

Comment: We no longer learn how to hunt animals or knap flint.  This saves time for other things.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the contributions of "giants" are ways to [simplify or visualize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) things to make a complex topic easier to learn and understand.  Other times the contribution is a way to [organize knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnaean_taxonomy) again making the body of scientific knowledge easier to learn and understand.